# How to make real-time connection Java and Flex?

Tags: java, apache-flex, connection, real-time

I'm still new at Flex. I want to make a flex code that request data to server everytime. 
I use java as a server.

Actually, i have successfully generate a linked-list of data at server from asterisk cli command. like this :

```
Name/username              Host            Dyn Nat ACL Port     Status    
2005                       (Unspecified)    D   N      0        UNKNOWN   
2004                       (Unspecified)    D   N      0        UNKNOWN   
2003                       (Unspecified)    D   N      0        UNKNOWN   
2002                       (Unspecified)    D   N      0        UNKNOWN   
2001/2001                  127.0.0.1        D   N      19134    OK (106 ms)
2000                       (Unspecified)    D   N      0        UNKNOWN   
6 sip peers [1 online , 5 offline]
```

I want to show this in flex user interface with real-time connection, what should I do?

i will appreciate your advice.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

To delivery data to a Flex application in real time, you'll need a server side piece that supports push functionality.  BlazeDS and GraniteDS do so using the Long Polling approach.  LiveCycle and WebORB support RTMP to do so.

Here is some [documentation for LiveCycle](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/LiveCycleDataServicesES/3.1/Developing/WS9d22440892c78ffa-3a437432122a8558cdf-8000Update.html) explaining more details.

Here is a [Blog post about doing this w/ BlazeDS](http://codeofdoom.com/wordpress/2009/01/29/blazeds-data-push-with-remote-objects/).

Comment: Red5 is generally considered a Media Server, not a Data Server, so as I understood it no.  But, check their documentation to be sure.

Comment: If you're after, specifically, what class you need to use to make this happen, then it appears that you need the Producer and the Consumer classes; more info in the docs I provided.

Answer (score 0):

It is a general question so here is a general answer.

It sounds like you're asking about messages that come from the server and go to the client.  The idea is that the server should update clients when data changes on the server.

The truth is that this kind of two-way communication isn't possible with HTTP (and Flex talks to Java over HTTP) but can be simulated (via polling or [comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)).

The two solutions I would recommend looking into are...

- Implement your own polling solution using a Flex [timer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html).
- Look into standard polling/comet solutions such as [BlazeDS](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/BlazeDS) or [GraniteDS](http://www.google.com/search?q=graniteds&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a)

Comment: Sorry, if my question too general. I means, is there any function at flex that handling real time communication?